# Why does docker mount a file with a numeric value as a directory?

Tags: macos, docker

Running a `docker run` command with:

```
-v=/path/to/file/name0.conf:/etc/name.conf
```

was resulting in the docker container not being started:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container <hash>: [9] System error: not a directory.
```

Why is this file not mounting in Docker?

I can make the name nameA.conf and mount it fine. The file nameA.conf and name0.conf are identical (verified with `diff`), have the same rights (verified with `ls -l`).

---

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does not mount files ending in numeric characters in their name correctly into containers.

It converts the file into a directory because of the `0` in the name - this can be reproduced with different filenames that are similar and have numeric characters.

The solution is to use non-numeric characters in the filename locally.